# Mutable @property?

Tags: python, python-3.9

Is there a way to define a **MUTABLE** (not just re-assignable !) property in Python ? I need a property that returns a list from a file, and changes said file when `__setitem__` is used on said list.

---

Example which does not work :

```
>>> import mmap
>>> def someClass():
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName

    @property
    def data(self):
        """Return data at start of eil in 4 byte chunks"""
        
        with open(self.fileName, mode = 'r+b') as f:
            with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as fmap:
                data = [fmap[i:i+4] for i in range(1024)]
        
        return data
    
    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        """Save data to file"""
        
        with open(self.fileName, mode = 'w+b') as f:
            with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE) as fmap:
                for i, data in enumerate(value):
                    fmap[i:i+4] = data

>>> a = someClass('C:\test.txt')
>>> a.data[0] == a.data[1]
False
>>> a.data[0] = a.data[1]
>>> a.data[0] == a.data[1]
False # Mutation did not register to file
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to return an ordinary `list` from the property in that case.  You'd need to return an instance of a custom class that overrides `__setitem__()` to write the changes to the file.

Comment: @quamrana done.

Comment: @jasonharper at that point it may just be simpler to expose the setter and getter methods directly, thankfully it's private code still so I don't need those things to be properties.It would just make other code clearer

Comment: NOTE: in the setter, you should open the file in write mode.

Comment: @RoyCohen I'll change it if it looks neater to you, but I have other code that writes to a mmap of a file in read mode and it works, so that's not the issue. Only the ```<access>``` parameter of the mmap counts on whether it can write or not

Comment: in C#' you can use an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) and subscribe to the CollectionChanged event. Maybe python has an equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't realy know anything about `mmap` so I might mess up the logic there but the general idea is the same.
As suggested in the comments by @jasonharper, the sulotion is to create a custome class that defines `__setitem__` and use it for `someClass().data`.

```py
class FileUpdatingList:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        with open(self.fileName, mode = 'r+b') as f:
            with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as fmap:
                return fmap[index:index+4]
    
    def __setitem__(self, index, data):
        with open(self.fileName, mode = 'w+b') as f:
            with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE) as fmap:
                fmap[index:index+4] = data
```

The problem now is that `someClass().data = value` is no longer valid, instead you must use `someClass.data[:] = value`. To solve this you can write a property to do that for you:

```py
def someClass():
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName
        self._data = FileUpdatingList(filename)

    @property
    def data(self):
        """Return data at start of eil in 4 byte chunks"""
        return self._data
    
    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        """Save data to file"""
        self._data[:] = value
```

Comment: mmap is just mapping a file's bytes to indexes so you can access them out of order, it's not very complciated ! Thanks, I'll see whether it makes sense to implement this, but regardless it's a good solution